# I'm styling a drop down menu that onclick will appear and on blur will disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Unfortunately I am having issues with the disappearing of the drop down. I'm currently using toggleClass to add/remove the class on click but I also need this process undone when the menu is blurred ie: clicking anywhere else on the page etc. Here is my jquery code:

```
$(function() {$('#srt-btn').click(function() {$('ul.toggle-off').toggleClass('toggle-on')});});

<ul id="sort">
<li><a id="srt-btn" class="srt-title">Sort ▾</a>
        <ul class="sort-menu toggle-off">
            <div class="droid"></div>
            <li class="top"><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="btm"><a href="#">Make List</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Do you also put all you JS on one line in your real code? If yes: don't. It introduces hard to spot mistakes. (Not an answer though)

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggleMenu() 
{   
     $('ul.toggle-off').toggleClass('toggle-on');
}


$(function() {
     $('#srt-btn').click(toggleMenu);
     $('#srt-btn').blur(toggleMenu);
});
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/S9mW3/3/)

Comment: This actually doesn't work. I can see why turning it into an actual function would be a nice idea but when clicked the function is either not running or doesn't work.

Comment: See this, please: http://jsfiddle.net/S9mW3/3/. You should use only one class for it's visibility. Or, if you need to use a "on" and a "off" class, you should togglem them **both**.

Comment: Only problem I'm having with that is the display settings. sort-menu has to be display:none; and when toggling the toggle-on class it tries to set it to display:block; but cant over ride the original display. That's why I have it toggling the way I do, but only problem is its not working. Im gonna try adjusting a few things and figuring out this display issue. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

you could also use stopPropagation to cancel click events

```
$(function() {
    $('#srt-btn').click(
        function(e) {
            $('ul.sort-menu').slideToggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    );
    $('.sort-menu li').click(
        function(e) {
            $('ul.sort-menu').slideUp();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    );
    $(document).click(
        function(){
            $('ul.sort-menu').slideUp();
        }
    );

});
```

And don't forget about setting your menu options ul to position:absolute else your elements will shift

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfLsF/3/)

Comment: Ok, now this one worked like a charm! Only thing I disliked was the animation that Ill be removing. Thanks for all of the help

Comment: anytime Brandon! im a fan of the minor animations, that's why i included it. maybe even a fast fade in fade out.. but your choice.. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var IsInside = false,
    $sortMenu = $('#sort'),
    $toggleOn = $('.toggle-off');

$sortMenu.on('mouseenter', '#srt-btn', function(){
  IsInside = true;
}).on('mouseleave', '#srt-btn', function(){
  IsInside = false;
});

$sortMenu.on('click', '#srt-btn', function(){
  $toggleOn.toggleClass('toggle-on');
});

$(document).on('click', 'body', function(){
  if(!IsInside) {
    $toggleOn.removeClass('toggle-on');
  }
});
```

Here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6JfG/).